# Importing Drupal 5 content into Drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, import, nodes

I need to import several thousand nodes from a Drupal 5 sql dump into a Drupal 6 website. I tried using Node Import and Import/Export API but very little success... any ideas as to how this can be done?

Many thanks!
Jane

Answer (score 2):

I used [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) on a Drupal 5 site to export the nodes into a csv file.

Then I used the [feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import the csv into a Drupal 6 site.